# Creating a file by merging two files

Tags: linux

I would like to merge two files and create a new file using Linux command.

I have the two files named as a1b.txt and a1c.txt

Content of a1b.txt

```
Hi,Hi,Hi
How,are,you
```

Content of a1c.txt

```
Hadoop|are|world
Data|Big|God
```

And I need a new  file called merged.txt with the below content(expected output)

```
Hi,Hi,Hi
How,are,you
Hadoop|are|world
Data|Big|God
```

To achieve that in terminal I am running the below command,but it gives me output like below

```
Hi,Hi,Hi
How,are,youHadoop|are|world
Data|Big|God


cat /home/cloudera/inputfiles/a1* > merged.txt
```

Could somebody help on getting the expected ouput

Comment: your commands ..works for me on bash..

Comment: But I need  each line falling in a new fresh line.but  I am getting that the last line of a1b.txt and first line of a1c.txt are falling in same line which I don't want .

Comment: That does not happen when i run those commands. Which shell are you using?

Comment: I am executing command  using terminal in Cloudera CDH3 distribution that Ubuntu 10 preinstalled it

Comment: Can you run `bash` and then try again?

Comment: cloudera@cloudera-vm:~/surender/localinputfiles$ bash
cloudera@cloudera-vm:~/surender/localinputfiles$ cat a1b.txt 
Hi,Hi,Hi
How,are,youcloudera@cloudera-vm:~/surender/localinputfiles$ cat a1c.txt 
Hadoop|are|world
Data|Big|Godcloudera@cloudera-vm:~/surender/localinputfiles$ cat a1*>merged.txt
cloudera@cloudera-vm:~/surender/localinputfiles$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your files do not have newline characters. Here is how to put the newline character to them.

```
 $ sed -i -e '$a\' /home/cloudera/inputfiles/a1*
 $ cat /home/cloudera/inputfiles/a1* > merged.txt
```

Comment: Specifically, the *very last line* in each of your files is missing a terminating newline character.  This is a common problem with files created with editors that mistakenly think `'\n'` is a line *separator* instead of a line *terminator*.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to be destructive (not have to keep the original two files unmodified) then:

`robert@debian:/tmp$ cat fileB.txt >> fileA.txt`

`robert@debian:/tmp$ cat fileA.txt 
this is file A
This is file B.`